# X.509 Standard set of attributes order

Tags: x509

I'm working with some legacy code, that implements a very basic X.509 parser. The code is quite old and I cannot distribute it.

This code reads the standard set of attributes in issuer and subject sequentially and in a specific order. As a basic example:

```
C=XX, O=MyOrganization, OU=MyOrganizationalUnit,
CN=myCommonName
```

So it would read the country, then the organization, and then the organizational unit and finally the common name.

I've been reading the standard (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.4), (see section 4.1.2.4 and 4.1.2.6) and this legacy code somehow works with most certificates.

The question is if this set of attributes must follow a specific order and where it says so or the opposite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for that specific order is that **Distinguished Names** (DNs) were defined in the [**X.500**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.500) series of standards. X.500 is about directory services. X.500 directory servers have been mostly replaced by LDAP servers, but X.509, the part of the series that defines certificates, has survived for other purposes.

In a directory tree the most general node is at the top (in your example *country*) and then narrows down on every level of the tree. A person is usually a leaf in this tree:

```
                 C=US
                  |
     O=Example1 ----- O=Example2
          |                |
  OU=OU1-----OU=OU2      ...
    |          |
  CN=XYZ      ...
```

AFAIK X.500 includes some rules that define which attribute type can follow a certain attribute type in the tree, but unfortunately the documents are not freely available.

The order of the relative distinguished names (RDNs) in the subject or issuer DN of a certificate on an **ASN.1** level reflects the order in the tree (i.e. top-down):

```
    SEQUENCE {
        SET {
            SEQUENCE {
                OBJECT IDENTIFIER=CountryName (2.5.4.6)
                PRINTABLE STRING='US'
            }
        }
        SET {
            SEQUENCE {
                OBJECT IDENTIFIER=OrganizationName (2.5.4.10)
                PRINTABLE STRING='GeoTrust Inc.'
            }
        }
        SET {
            SEQUENCE {
                OBJECT IDENTIFIER=CommonName (2.5.4.3)
                PRINTABLE STRING='GeoTrust Global CA'
            }
        }
    }
```

However, for the **string representation** of a DN there are two standards:  OpenSSL shows the attributes by default as they are actually stored in the certificate, while RFC [2253](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2253.txt)/[4514](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4514.txt) reverses the order:

> ... the output consists of the string encodings of each
>      RelativeDistinguishedName in the RDNSequence (according to Section
>      2.2), starting with the last element of the sequence and moving
>      backwards toward the first.

```
CN=GeoTrust Global CA,O=GeoTrust Inc.,C=US
```

Also note that there are certificates "*in the wild*" which have multiple OUs in their DNs or less common attribute types from [RFC 4519](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4519.txt) like SERIALNUMBER or UID. I have also seen quite a few certificates, where the RDNs were actually encoded in the wrong order.

Comment: To be more specific, RDN attribute order in the certificate subject doesn't matter. There is a convention, but it is not strictly enforced, because although subject field uses X.500 name format, it does not belong to any X.500 tree.

Comment: @CryptoGuy I think it does matter when they're DER encoded as I've found the following cite in various sources: "Elements of a Set are encoded in sorted order, based on their tag value" (please, correct me if I'm wrong). However, both your comment and the answer, have helped me to understand why this ugly legacy code was working at all. Thanks for that!

Comment: `SET` is an unordered sequence. This means that nested types (RDN attributes) may appear in any order. It is just a convention to order them in some particular order.

Comment: @CryptoGuy Name is a `SEQUENCE` of RDNs, not a `SET`. The SET is only relevant for multi-valued RDNs. And even then there is an order because - as FranMowinckel pointed out - X.509 certificates are DER encoded.

Comment: DER encoding doesn't matter here, because it is just encoding. Thanks for correcting me on Sequence, I forgon about that. However, there still is no particular order when placing RDN attributes. You can set name in this order `CN=some name, OU=org unit, O=org` or in this order: `OU=org unit, CN=some name, O=org`. For subject field they both would mean the same.

Comment: @CryptoGuy DER encoding is crucial for certificates, because for digital signatures to work there has to be exactly one way to encode the content. If you change the order of the RDNs, it becomes a different certificate and signature verification would fail.

Comment: @CryptoGuy Also, certificate path validation would fail if you simply change the order of the RDNs. Quote from RFC 5280: "CAs MUST encode the distinguished name in the subject field of a CA certificate identically to the distinguished name in the issuer field in certificates issued by that CA.  If CAs use different encodings, implementations might fail to recognize name chains for paths that include this certificate.  As a consequence, valid paths could be rejected."

Comment: I think, the question was a bit different. The question was whether the RDN attribute is important while parsing an X.500 name. The answer is: no, there is no importance. While parsing the name, you should expect any order without a limitation. You may expect duplicate attributes in any sequence (say, multiple CN or DC attributes). There was no question about name matching or binding, because it is a different story.

Comment: @CryptoGuy Yeah, sure, we agree on that. I was just trying to clarify some of cour comments.